# Spring- whitelable error page: This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm learning a Spring Boot project online, but even though I followed everything in the video, my code doesn't work as expected. I keep getting a whitelabel page.
Here is my code below:

Controller I have removed demo sorry for the confusion.

```
 @RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class EmployeeController {
    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;
@GetMapping("/employees")
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
    //System.out.println(employeeRepository.findAll());
        return employeeRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

application

```
import com.example.springboot.model.Employee;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {

}
```

application properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee_management_system
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=


spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
```

pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>springboot-backend</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>springboot-backend</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Here is message in the console:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.0.5)

2023-04-20T14:04:02.315-04:00  INFO 15092 --- [           main] c.e.s.ServletInitializer                 : Starting ServletInitializer using Java 17.0.2 with PID 15092 (F:\Javaproject-playground\springboot-backend\target\classes started by billz in C:\Users\billz\.SmartTomcat\springboot-backend\springboot-backend)
2023-04-20T14:04:02.319-04:00  INFO 15092 --- [           main] c.e.s.ServletInitializer                 : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-04-20T14:04:02.439-04:00  INFO 15092 --- [           main] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2023-04-20T14:04:03.450-04:00  INFO 15092 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-04-20T14:04:03.494-04:00  INFO 15092 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 22 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-04-20T14:04:03.959-04:00  INFO 15092 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1516 ms
2023-04-20T14:04:04.372-04:00  INFO 15092 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-04-20T14:04:04.519-04:00  INFO 15092 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.7.Final
2023-04-20T14:04:05.245-04:00  INFO 15092 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-04-20T14:04:05.806-04:00  INFO 15092 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@563a32a2
2023-04-20T14:04:05.809-04:00  INFO 15092 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-04-20T14:04:05.898-04:00  INFO 15092 --- [           main] SQL dialect                              : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
2023-04-20T14:04:07.519-04:00  INFO 15092 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2023-04-20T14:04:07.540-04:00  INFO 15092 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-04-20T14:04:07.658-04:00  WARN 15092 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2023-04-20T14:04:08.289-04:00  INFO 15092 --- [           main] c.e.s.ServletInitializer                 : Started ServletInitializer in 6.725 seconds (process running for 11.033)
20-Apr-2023 14:04:08.342  [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor[C:\Users\billz\.SmartTomcat\springboot-backend\springboot-backend\conf\Catalina\localhost\demo.xml][10,348]ms
20-Apr-2023 14:04:08.344  [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start ["http-nio-8080"]
20-Apr-2023 14:04:08.362  [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start [10426]
http://localhost:8080/demo
2023-04-20T14:04:30.050-04:00  INFO 15092 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-04-20T14:04:30.051-04:00  INFO 15092 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
```

It was supposed to load all the employees on the website at localhost:8080/demo/api/v1/employees, but instead I got a whitelabel page.
I don't know what I did wrong. Is it possible that I'm using Tomcat through Intellij Community Edition, causing this problem? I set the context path as '/demo'.
Thank you so much for any help!

Comment: Edit question to add exact error and the stacktrace.

Comment: If you have context path set to demo then remove demo from the controller request mapping path.

Comment: Remove `/demo` from `@RequestMapping("/demo/api/v1")`

Comment: I have removed `/demo' still no luck.

Comment: can you provide error message or stacktrace please?

Comment: also how/where did you set context path as '/demo'. More information please.

Comment: Thank you for your replies!
I use Smart Tomcat plugin, in run configuration set context path.

Comment: be sure to set context path : "server.servlet.context-path=/demo" in the application.properties file

Comment: Did you remember to build the project before running it?

Comment: Never mind I switched to other IDE works fine. Something weird going on I dont know.

Answer (score 0):

If the context path is "/demo" and the path to the controller method is "/demo/api/v1/employees", then the URL you need to use is the following:

```
localhost:8080/demo/demo/api/v1/employees
```

Comment: I have changed path multiple times and wont work. I tried your url is still whitelable page